# Calculating time using modulus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

In my textbook, the question is as follows:

What time does a 24 hour clock read:

a) 100 hours after it reads 2:00

b) 45 hours before it reads 12:00

c) 168 hours after it reads 19:00

And provides answers as follows:

a) 7:00

b) 8:00

c) 10:00

I calculated (a) by say t = 100 + 2 (mod 24), then 2:00 + t, which gave me 8:00.

Now my problem is, i dont understand a) how they arrived at those answers, and b) where my understanding of modulo arithmetic is lacking. When i searched for the worked solution of these questions on google, all the sources with these specific questions had a different answer from that of the book(but the answers from all the sources were the same), for example, all sources say a) is 6:00. This inconsistency has left me confused. In answering, please also show how you would do the same for a 12-hour clock.

Comment: Daylight saving? ;)

Comment: Thankfully, we can safely assume that we can ignore daylight savings.  Be sure that you understand the difference between the questions "*what is the time currently if $100$ hours in the future it will read $2:00$?*" versus "*what time will it be $100$ hours in the future if the current time is $2:00$?*"  In the first version of the question this corresponds to $t+100\equiv 2\pmod{24}$ whereas the second version of the question corresponds to $t\equiv 2+100\pmod{24}$

Comment: For your calculation for part (a), it appears that you are adding $2$ twice. The answer should be $((100+2)\bmod {24}):00$.

Comment: @peterwhy I disagree.  Given the wording, current time is $t$.  Time in $100$ hours is $t+100\pmod{24}$.  Time in $100$ hours is known to be $2$.  Would it not be $(-100+2)\pmod{24}$ instead?

Comment: @JMoravitz My understanding of the wording is that: at an instance, the clock reads $2:00$, then what time does it read $100$ hours after that instance?

Comment: I guess this brings me back to my original comment then with the two similarly worded but fundamentally different possible questions.  Which brings us to @ vernon to clarify which is meant.  There could possibly be a translation difficulty at play (or he doesn't realize that missing a single word can dramatically change the meaning of a question).  So, vernon, for (a) is the *current time* 2:00?  Or is the *future time* one hundred hours into the future 2:00?  Certainly, in either interpretation, the answer of seven is definitely incorrect (all numbers used in (a) are even so can't be odd).

Answer (score 3):

If the **current time** is $t$, and the time $n$ hours into the **future** is $f$, using a $24$ hour clock, we have:

$t$ is the current time.  $t+n$ is the future time.  $f$ is also the future time.  Thus:

$$t+n\equiv f\pmod{24}$$

using a twelve hour clock, this is instead simply $t+n\equiv f\pmod{12}$

---

If the current time is 2:00, and we want to know what the future time is 100 hours into the future, we have:

$f\equiv t+n\equiv 2+100\equiv 102\equiv 4\cdot 24+6\equiv 6\pmod{24}$

so the future time will read 06:00

---

If the current time is $t$ (*currently unknown*), and $100$ hours into the future the clock reads $2:00$ (*the future time*), we have:

$t+n\equiv f\pmod{24}$ implying

$t\equiv f-n\equiv 2 - 100\equiv -98\equiv -5\cdot 24 + 22\equiv 22\pmod{24}$

so the current time reads 22:00

---

Similarly, we could talk about time into the past.

If the **current time** is $t$ and the time $n$ hours *before it* into the **past** is $p$, using a $24$ hour clock we have:

$t$ is the current time.  $t-n$ is the past time.  $p$ is the past time.  Thus:

$$t-n\equiv p\pmod{24}$$

---

If the *current time* is 12:00 and we are curious what time it was 45 hours into the past, we have:

$p \equiv t-n\equiv 12 - 45\equiv -33\equiv -2\cdot 24 + 15\equiv 15\pmod{24}$

thus, the time 45 hours in the past was 15:00

---

If the *current time* is unknown, $t$, but we know that 45 hours into the past the time had at that point read as 12:00, we have:

$t\equiv n+p\equiv 45+12\equiv 57\equiv 2\cdot 24 + 9\equiv 9\pmod{24}$

so, the current time is 9:00.

Again, in all of these examples, if you were using a twelve hour clock instead, you would use modulo twelve.  In each case, you are asking "how much larger than the closest smaller multiple of twenty-four (*or twelve as the case may be*) is my number?"

Comment: Excellent answer. What about daylight saving?

Comment: A complication to the problem that goes beyond the scope of the original problem.  If you want to add the complication, then essentially add an if-then statement to the answer which adjusts either forward or back an hour respectively.